# Is it possible to rewrite URLs in this situation?

Tags: url-rewriting

I am using a fantastic plugin called [*Query Multiple Taxonomies*](http://scribu.net/wordpress/query-multiple-taxonomies) which provides a widget to "drill down" by category / tag and other custom taxonomies you may have.

The site is [livetonom.com](http://www.livetonom.com/).

The widget (on the sidebar) gives URLS ending:

```
/?category_name=restaurants&locations=london
```

Is it possible to rewrite that to something like:

```
/restaurants/london
```

I tried using a rewrite rule generators but stuff like this added directly to `.htaccess` did not work:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?category_name=$1&locations=$2 [L]
```

I'm not even sure that adding to `.htaccess` directly is correct or will work - can anyone let me know if this is a non-starter or how I go about this?

Comment: Well, maybe we should see what @scribu has to say...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with .htaccess and rewrite rules

What you might consider is a 301 redirect in your .htaccess like this

```
#fancy name redirect here
redirectMatch 301 ^/restaurant/london(.*)$ /?category_name=restaurants&locations=london
```

Basically you can then tell people to go to your own friendly URL and they get redirected to the longer one that WordPress uses.

I'd have a look at [Perishable Press stupid tricks with .htaccess](http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/)

As another point of reference you can use go to WordPress Admin > Settings > Permalinks and change the word Category to Restaurants -- but that will mean all your 'categories' are now 'restaurants'